# Unable to subscribe to Microsoft Graph API Calendar is user has apostrophe in name

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-calendar

We have an application set up in Office 365. The customer has given Admin Consent to `Calendar.ReadWrite` access for all users’ calendars in the tenant.

Our web application is able to [set up subscriptions for change notifications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/subscription-post-subscriptions?view=graph-rest-1.0) except for users with an apostrophe in their email address (i.e. `John.O’Neil@nonwhere.com`)

Subscription requests results in the following error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "ExtensionError",
    "message": "Operation: Create; Exception: [Status Code: ServiceUnavailable; Reason: Mailbox info is stale.]",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "11a8e561-0966-49aa-ac87-f884c1582764",
      "date": "2019-02-25T22:46:40"
    }
  }
}
```

This issue is seen with users in multiple tenants for the same application. We are able to reproduce this in our test tenant.

In our testing, authorization with application bearer token fails to subscribe to those users’ calendar, who has an apostrophe in the email address. Application is able to subscribe correctly to other users’ calendar who does not have an apostrophe in the email address.

Also, the same EXACT request succeeds with user’s own token for authorization header. So, it looks like application processing has a different code path that errors for users with an apostrophe in the email address.

Comment: we are investigating this and will get back to you.

Comment: Andrew, are you using a different resource path (/me/messages) when subscribing using the user's own token? It will be good if you can share the sample requests for both cases here.

Comment: You may also want to try subscribing using their `id` rather than their `userPrincipalName`.

Comment: @JeremyThakeMSFT any update here? It's over a year of this issue.

Comment: recommendation we got was to resolve the id and subscribe to the ID